# Store data between controllers as uique

Tags: javascript, angularjs, setinterval

I have a controller which, I have expected, will contain unique data, gather as follow:

```
        setInterval(function() {

            dataStorage.setData('maxTime',maxTime);
            dataStorage.setData('currentTime',currentTime);
            dataStorage.setData('previousTime',previousTime);

            var dMaxTime = dataStorage.getData('maxTime');
            var dCurrentTime = dataStorage.getData('currentTime');
            var dPreviousTime = dataStorage.getData('previousTime');

            $log.debug("Max time  " + dMaxTime);
            $log.debug("Current time " + dCurrentTime);
            $log.debug("Previous time " + dPreviousTime)

        }, 2000);
```

which uses simple factory to capture data between controllers

```
myApp.factory('dataStorage', [function() {

    var dataInfo = [];

    return {

        setData: function (key, data) {
            dataInfo[key] = data;
        },
        getData: function (key) {
            return dataInfo[key];
        }

    };
}]);
```

but when I go back and forth to the view which has first code above it stores the same variables again but with different (updated values) and then displays them in the log as how many times that view with controller was hit.

Is there any way to prevent that and to have stored only most recent captured data?

Comment: can you expand your controller code a bit more? Where is your maxTime,currentTime,previousTime defined? Also, what is the problem? Is it logging too many times? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @Vincent yes, it logging too many times (like 3, 4 times with different values)

Comment: Suggest you move all that business logic from controller to service

Comment: You may just be forgetting to clear your interval when the controller is destroyed.

Comment: @Vincent Good idea. I will check that and update OP

Comment: @Vincent Yeah, it was not clearing `$interval` on a controller destroy. You can post it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the controller is destroyed, you need to clear your interval, otherwise it continues to run.

```
app.controller('SomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    console.log('whatever')
  }, 2000);

  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  });

}]);
```